# INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (auto-increment ID)

Tags: php, sql

I use this code to insert or update the race_id on webpage_race table. Every time I use it I become a new new auto-increment ID. How can I stop it?

```
<?php

foreach($race_obj as $key => $race_value){
    if(!empty($race_value->race_id)){$race_id = $race_value->race_id;}else{$race_id = 'null';}

    $sql = '
    INSERT INTO webpage_race
    (race_id)
    VALUES
    ('.$race_id.')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    race_id             = VALUES(race_id)
    ;
    ';
    
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
     $message = '<p align="center">New record created successfully<br>';
    }else{
        $message = "Error: " . $conn->error.'<br>';
    }
    echo $message;
}
```

Comment: What's the PK or index of table `webpage_race`?

Comment: the PK is web_id the race_id is UNIQUE

Comment: @NikosKioses That is how insert.. on duplicate key update works. Marking the relevant dupe now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on @nice_dev comment

I change the database engine from InnoDB to MyIsam and my issue is solved.